# Setting up Symfony2 with PHPStorm 7.1.3 not working

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, phpstorm

I am trying to setup Symfony2 with PHPStorm 7.1.3 using [these](http://www.kevwebdev.com/blog/setting-up-a-symfony2-project-in-phpstorm.html#php-interpreter) instructions but I am running into an error when i execute `php app/console server:run`.

The error I see is

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.
```

[image]

This is what my development machine has

```
WAMP: 2.5
PHP : 5.5.12
OS  : Windows 7
```

So after getting this error I went to google to do some search and saw many people who had similar problem were using PHP 5.3 and the command line was built for PHP5.4 on wards. I then installed a new version of WAMP which came with PHP 5.5.12 assuming and hoping the error to go away and let me move on to development but then I got the same error again. Now something tells me may be I did not configure something right so I went to see the PHP settings and all seems fine to me.
[image]

I am not sure what else to do to get it to work, I will really appreciate if anyone can guide me in setting up Symfony2 with PHPStorm.

UPDATE:

I ran a command `php -v` to double the php version and it says **PHP 5.3.13** 
[image]

Comment: If this depends on PHP version -- then what PHP version do you ACTUALLY have? You are executing this command in Terminal (same as normal console: cmd.exe) -- it has no relation to the PHP Interpreter settings in IDE -- it uses your system wide php. I suggest executing "php -v" in terminal -- maybe you have more than one PHP on your computer. Right now I see no way how this problem is connected to PhpStorm.

Comment: P.S. Terminal and "Command Line Tool Support" plugin (mentioned in that manual) are two different things. First is the same as your real console/terminal .. while second is some custom emulator (don't know better word/term) which can use PHP Interpreter from PhpStorm settings if configured accordingly (as per manual).

Comment: if i run the command `php -v`, the output i get is PHP 5.3.13, i have added a screenshot at the end of my question

Comment: The only console I am using is `command line tool support` that comes with phpstorm

Comment: It does not matter to me what console/tool i use to run the application as long as i can get to the development. If you know any fix/solution to this please let me know and I am not saying that this is related to PHPStorm, i am just asking for help to get it up and running

Comment: 1) Your screenshots CLEARLY show that you are using TERMINAL and not CLT 2) If you want to use CLT -- it's under `Tools | Run Command...` 3) Better fix your system-wide PHP to point to your 5.5 version (i.e. alter your `PATH` environment variable (`My Computer | Right click | Properties | Advanced System Settings | Advanced | Environment variables...`) and place folder where correct PHP 5.5 is located in front of the list). Or  just use FULL path to correct php.exe instead of just `php`

Comment: thanks alot, this did help and i am able to move on to development, would you like to add your comment as an answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **clearly** using Terminal and not Command Line Tools (CLT). The manual you are referring to was made for older version where terminal was not yet available and it refers to CLT (which you are NOT using).

Since you are using Terminal, make sure that your system-wide PHP is actually v5.5. You can verify this by executing `php -v` command.

Terminal and "Command Line Tool Support" plugin are two different things. First is the same as your real console/terminal (e.g. `cmd.exe` on Windows) .. while second is some custom emulator (don't know better word/term) which can use PHP Interpreter from PhpStorm settings if configured accordingly (as per manual).

---

**If you want to use Command Line Tools:**

It is located at `Tools | Run Command...` .

Make sure that you have created `php` alias (as per that manual) so it refers to currently select PHP Interpreter from IDE settings. Otherwise `php` command may fail. Aliases can be configured at `Settings | Command Line Tool Support`.

---

**If you want to use Terminal:**

You have 2 choices here:

1. Use FULL path to correct `php.exe` instead of just `php`
2. Make php v5.5 default system-wide. For this you have to:

   - Alter your `PATH` environment variable  (`My Computer | Right click | Properties | Advanced System Settings | Advanced | Environment variables...`) and place folder where correct PHP 5.5 is located in front of the list
   - Restart IDE (most likely will be required) so it picks up these changes to environment variables.